# Why Am I Receiving this NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working through a Ruby on Rails tutorial for creating a blog and I have received this error when I go to bring up the page in my localhost:3000 address:

'undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass'

My Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def new
end

def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end

def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
 end

def index
  @posts = Post.all 
end
end
```

My View File:

```
<h1>Listing posts</h1>


    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Text</th>
      </tr>

      <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= post.title %></td>
          <td><%= post.text %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </table>
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move *index* action away from *private* section.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `PostsController#index` method is private, so its code doesn't run when you enter `/posts`, so `@posts` instance variable remains `nil`.

Move it to public section:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @posts = Post.all 
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end
end
```

Comment: There's gotta be another way; specifically in the tutorial it states to use the private definition.

Comment: Wait, I think I understand better; you mean structurally, to place the private elsewhere.

Comment: @user2698988 show me this tutorial, please. 
And no, there's not another way to make `index` method an action definition. BTW why do you want it to be private?

Comment: @user2698988 I mean you should put `index` definition outside of `private` section.